# What to do when question and answers get mass-upvoted with no reason?

Tags: discussion, up-votes

I answered a not-so-interesting question on Stack Overflow giving just a short example rather than a complete answer. Since yesterday the question was upvoted 44 times and my answer 55 times!

Even if I'm happy with the reputation I don't think this is normal. Should I do something or can I do something, maybe like flagging the question?

Comment: Jon Skeet was involved in the question. He is an upvote magnet. You got caught in the crossfire. Case closed.

Comment: Seems it got upvoted for a reason alright. It was the correct answer and the question itself got a lot of attention. Nothing to be worried about. What could/should a moderator do about any of it?

Comment: Enjoy the ride :) I have one similarly voted answer that makes me scratch my head. (Different circumstances)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Due to the reputation cap, you can only get 200 reputation per day so it's not like those upvotes are *severely* affecting your reputation. If you really feel so bad about getting it all from one answer, go answer some other questions and get upvotes that don't count. That way you can pretend that you got reputation from those answers and the other one just filled in the rest. Kind of like what I'm doing right now. I've already hit the reputation cap here on meta for the day, but I'm still answering anyways. :)

Really there's nothing to be worried about. Some questions just attract a lot of views, especially when someone like Jon Skeet answers them. Lots of views sometimes equates to lots of upvotes on unexpecting answers.

Comment: OK, thanks for your answer. I better understand the context now.

Answer (score 5):

There's usually no need to do anything in this case.

People have various reasons for massively upvoting questions/answers:

- [Funny](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)
- [Daft Punk](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10760494/298479), plus being [reddited](http://www.reddit.com/r/programming/comments/u4yzl/the_perfect_time_to_use_daft_punk_as_an_example/)
- Extremely good/thorough
- A question that receives high traffic from the front page. Often that's something very simple in a common tag such as [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery) or [php](/questions/tagged/php). Lots of people open it with the intent to answer it, but then see an existing good answer and upvote it.